# Is it possible to restore global_step in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

keras can save model with `tf.keras.models.save_model()`, then restore model from `tf.keras.models.load_model()`

Here is a scenario,

1. train a model `x` step. save the weights to checkpoint file. `save_format='tf'`
2. restore weight from checkpoint file, train another `x` step.
3. In tensorflow the starting global step of 2nd training is `x+1` step, but in keras, it seems that it reset the global steps.

**So far, this behavior cause me 2 problems.**

1. tensorboad is messing up, the 2 training run all start from step 0. [tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkDat.jpg)
2. I need save some information into file during the training, the file name will depends on the train step, so I can save information for different steps, eg: weight_1000steps, weight_2000steps, etc. But since step will restart if I start a new training, so some old file will be overwritten.

How can I restore the training step/epoch from model file in keras? (`tf.__version_ is '2.3.1'`)

Answer (score 2):

In Keras, the optimizers keep track of the iterations themselves and their iteration counter is persisted in the checkpoints. It is available as [optimizer attribute](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#attributes_1) `model.optimizer.iterations`.

You can compute the corresponding epoch number from this and use it to adjust the epoch number for tensorboard using the parameter `init_epoch` of [model.fit()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit).

I haven't found a documented way to adjust the step number for tensorboard, but at least for current tensorflow (2.4) it can be done by altering the model's (internal!) field _train_counter with a [callback](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback?hl=en) passed in the `callbacks` parameter of [model.fit()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit):

```py
class UseOptimizerIterationAsTrainStep(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def set_model(self, model):
        self.model = model

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        self.model._train_counter.assign(self.model.optimizer.iterations)
```

Of course this may break again in future tensorflow versions.